# Url in template from site-package

Tags: python, html, django

i'm building my first Django app so i'm know i'm missing a lot of things, but i installed a gallery for my site and is inside site-packages, i set the url inside urls.py and it looks like this :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from contacto.views import Home,Contacto



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('gallery/', include('gallery.urls'),name='gallery'),
    path('home/',Home,name='home'),
    path('contacto/',Contacto,name='contacto')

]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I can perfectly access the gallery and its functionalities if i write the url in the browser,  but i cannot reference the gallery Url inside my template like the other Urls using {% url 'gallery' %}, i keep getting this error :

> Reverse for 'gallery' not found. 'gallery' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Also heres the gallery url:

```
from django.urls import path

from gallery.views import ImageView, ImageList, AlbumView, AlbumList, ImageCreate


app_name = 'gallery'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', AlbumList.as_view(), name='album_list'),
    path('images/', ImageList.as_view(), name='image_list'),
    path('image/<int:pk>/<slug>', ImageView.as_view(), name='image_detail'),
    path('upload/', ImageCreate.as_view(), name='image_upload'),
    path('album/<int:pk>/<slug>/', AlbumView.as_view(), name='album_detail'),
    path('album/<int:apk>/<int:pk>/<slug>', ImageView.as_view(), name='album_image_detail')
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: post your gallery url also

Comment: You can't assign an `include` a `name=`. Use `gallery:album_list` instead

Comment: that was the problem it seems, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
app_name = 'gallery'
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('gallery/', include('gallery.urls')),
    path('home/',Home,name='home'),
    path('contacto/',Contacto,name='contacto')

]
```

Change it as shown above and call `gallery:album_list` for album list, and follow same pattern for others